# How can I stop a div that is scrolling over the navbar?

Tags: css

Recently I am working on a new website and I am creating it with bootstrap. Here is the bootply link that have my website.

http://www.bootply.com/9pUX4JwEYb

According to that HTML in this Link, I have a trouble that i cant fix yet. When I am scrolling up, the text "Main Bodysssss..." is going over the navigation bar. I have tried to position it but no help. Just tell me how to fix this. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A higher [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) for `.navbar` should fix this ([working example](http://www.bootply.com/9nB9eZz1Lq#)):

```
.navbar {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index),

> When elements overlap, z-order determines which one covers the other.
>   An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a
>   lower one.